# How to get app inventor xml code in my eclipse IDE

Tags: android, app-inventor

How can i get App Inventor XMl code for Eclipse IDE

Comment: Please update this when a solution is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, not possible, as App Inventor does not manage Eclipse Java projects, but uses schema. Use "Download Source" (More Actions) in the list of "My projects" to inspect the code generated by App inventor.

Answer (score 0):

Though its not possible for the time being

I've read in forums that it'll be possible in near future versions of app-inventor

Keep Checking forum announcements for any update

Answer (score 0):

Currently not possible,
I will prefer to design your app with eclipse built in GUI plugin.